# How to get Time Complexity(Big-O) on this recursive function?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

How to get Time Complexity this function?

```
fun(int n){
     for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
         for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
       print(" ");
       }
     }
    fun(n-3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the run time of f(n) is T(n). You have to loops in each function call. so The compelxity of the loops are O(n^2).

the f(n) has 2 loops ( O(n^2) ) and one f(n-3). so we come up to the equation below:

```
T(n) = T(n-3) + O(n^2)
```

which also can be written as:

```
T(n) = T(n-3) + (n^2)*(1^n)
```

So the equal equation to a above is: `(r^3 - 1 )[(r-1)^3]=0`

so we have `r=1 ( 6th degree)` so the T(n) will be like this:

```
T(n) = [a1 + a2*n + a3*n^2 + a4*n^3 + a5*n^4 + a6*n^5 ]*(1^n)
```

So at last it is obvious that for `a1,a2,a3,a4,a4,a5,a6!=0` (which only can be found by initial value of f(n), the result is

```
T(n) = O(n^5)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no bottom to the recursion, so it will run infinitely long. Since the growth rate of the function is independent of the input (n), it is an O(1) function (no matter how big n is, the execution time is always the same, which is to say, infinite).

If there *were* a bottom to the recursion, we can see how fast the function grows for higher values of n. Each n adds another pass through the inner loop, multiplied by another pass through the outer loop, multiplied by the recursion depth, so that is n*n*n = O(n^3).

It is true that the recursion grows a little bit more slowly than the two loops, but in the end it *does* grow linearly with n, which means it counts as O(n) in its own right.